# Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'int'. An explicit conversion error exists

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

My code shows 5 errors. The errors says that,

Error   1   The best overloaded method match for 'System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.ObjectCollection.AddRange(object[])' has some invalid arguments

Error   2   Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Array' to 'object[]'

Error   3   Cannot convert method group 'ReadExisting' to non-delegate type 'float'. Did you intend to invoke the method?

Error   4   Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'int'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Error   5   Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'string'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private void Form2(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.CenterToParent();
            BtnCon.Enabled = false;
            BtnCon.BringToFront();

            BtnDiscon.Enabled = false;
            BtnDiscon.SendToBack();

            cmbBaud.SelectedItem = "9600";
        }

        private void BtnScanPort_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CmbPort.Items.Clear();
            Array myPort;
            int i;
            myPort = System.IO.Ports.SerialPort.GetPortNames();
            CmbPort.Items.AddRange(myPort);
            i = CmbPort.Items.Count;
            i = i - i;
            try
            {
                CmbPort.SelectedIndex = i;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                DialogResult result;
                result = MessageBox.Show("com port not detected", "Warning !!!",                MessageBoxButtons.OK);
                CmbPort.Text = "";
                CmbPort.Items.Clear();
                Form2(this, e);
            }
            BtnCon.Enabled = true;
            BtnCon.BringToFront();
            CmbPort.DroppedDown = true;
        }

        private void cmbPort_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e){}

        private void label2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){}

        private void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                float i = serialPort1.ReadExisting;
                LblValue.Text = "Value : " + i.ToString();
            }
            catch (Exception ex){}
        }

        private void BtnCon_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            BtnCon.Enabled = false;
            BtnCon.SendToBack();

            serialPort1.BaudRate = cmbBaud.SelectedItem;
            serialPort1.PortName = CmbPort.SelectedItem;
            serialPort1.Open();
            Timer1.Start();

            BtnDiscon.Enabled = true;
            BtnDiscon.BringToFront();
        }

        private void BtnDiscon_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            BtnDiscon.Enabled = false;
            BtnDiscon.SendToBack();

            Timer1.Stop();
            serialPort1.Close();

            BtnCon.Enabled = true;
            BtnCon.BringToFront();
        }
    }
}
```

Need to correct those errors.

Comment: Which lines of code give the errors?

Comment: there are multiple issues in your code, you need to learn about data types

Comment: Please properly indent your code.

Comment: CmbPort.Items.AddRange(myPort);

Comment: float i = serialPort1.ReadExisting;

Comment: serialPort1.BaudRate = cmbBaud.SelectedItem;
    serialPort1.PortName = CmbPort.SelectedItem;

Comment: These are the  lines of code give the errors

Comment: Can you give me a solution for these errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first error is because of this: `Array myPort;`. That's not how you declare an array, `Array` is an abstract class that provides methods to operate on arrays. `SerialPort.GetPortNames()` returns a string array so you can either declare a string array or just remove the `Array myPort;` declaration and replace the other line with

`var myPort = System.IO.Ports.SerialPort.GetPortNames();`.

The next issue is with `float i = serialPort1.ReadExisting;`, it's a method so you have to invoke it i.e. `serialPort1.ReadExisting()`. I think that method has a return type of string so you don't need to make it a float either, it looks like you're using it as a string in the next line anyway so `i` doesn't have to be a float.

The other errors are because you are trying to assign a combobox selected item to int and string values but a selected item is an object, you have to cast it to the desired type e.g.

`serialPort1.BaudRate =  (int)cmbBaud.SelectedItem;`